# I need to get a distinct list based on a column in SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

```
var sqlStatement = string.Format("select * from CardDecks where deckid = {0}", id);
var getcardid = db.CardDecks.SqlQuery(sqlStatement).ToList();
var getDistinct = getcardid.Distinct().ToList();
```

What I expect from this code is for the last list to only pull distinct values but it still pulls duplicates. I need for it to only pull back the list with unique values based on cardid. What am I missing?

Comment: Why not use "DIstinct" in your SQL statement?

Comment: I could do that.... I am not sure how to specify which column/syntax.

Comment: Duplicates how? When speaking SQL, we mean the whole selected rows...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the SQL statement to this and it works:

```
   List<CardDeck> distictList = getcardid.GroupBy(p => p.CardID).Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your query like this:

```
select distinct column1, column2, column3 from CardDecks where deckid = {0}
```

... where `column1, column2, column3` are the columns that you want to show.

Comment: That brings back all the duplicates. :(